# Using bind and Kliesli composition operators with Result

Tags: f#, monads

I'm trying to use the bind (`>>=`) and Kleisli composition (`>=>`) operators with the basic `Result` type, but either they are not defined or are not in scope:

```ml
let f x =
  if x%2 = 0 then Ok (x/2)
  else            Error ()

let ff x = Ok x >>= f >>= f
let ff' = f >=> f

[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ =
  printfn "%A" (ff 12)
  printfn "%A" (ff' 28)
  0
```

> **Error FS0043** Expecting a type supporting the operator '>>=' but given a function type. You may be missing an argument to a function.

I've tried to `open` a few different namespaces to bring the definition into scope, but no luck.

It seems from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42816639/make-fish-in-f) like the operators can't be defined in general without extensions, but are there definitions for the standard `Result` anywhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haskell-like operators are not defined in the F# core library, nor are they likely to ever be. You'll need to either write them in your own prelude, or use a library like [FSharpPlus](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpPlus/) for these and other more Haskell-like (Well, typelevel) programming approaches.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what Phillip said in his answer, it might be useful to add that you can rewrite your example using the built-in `Result.bind` operation and function composition or piping:

```
let f x =
  if x%2 = 0 then Ok (x/2)
  else Error ()

let ff x = Ok x |> Result.bind f |> Result.bind f
let ff' = f >> Result.bind f

printfn "%A" (ff 12)
printfn "%A" (ff' 28)
```

This is of course just a toy example, so it's hard to say what you actually want to do, but if I was trying to use `Result`, my first choice would be to use the standard library functions - they may make your code longer, but it is arguably more readable.

Comment: It's a question of familiarity. Personally I find the Haskell `>>=` operator very readable.

Comment: I use Result.bind (or similar) when I want other coders (or future me) to notice that I expect `Result<'a,'b>`. I use `>>=` (or similar) when I want other coders (or future me) to focus on the bound function, not which monad we're in.